# Building a localized stack-exchange community

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community

I am thinking about creating a local area stack exchange community. For example there are plenty of developers that just don't know English well enough to participate in StackOverflow discussions. Launching a language-specific community may prove useful.

The main question is how did StackOverflow initially manage to get the first people to ask questions and, more importantly, get the professionals to be here to answer them?

Do I need to personally contact a few dozen developers and ask them to check the question list? Then, I can advertise on discussion boards that certain technology specialist of this country are there to answer, and the questions will come pouring in?

Comment: Are you asking how to build a language-specific alternative to SO on the SO site?

Comment: @JNK'sMetAccount a language specific alternative to SO using StackExchange engine. The question is not about technology, but about how SO managed to get the initial "crowed" in.

Comment: I realize that, but I think it's kind of a strange request.  `Can you tell me how you were successful so I can do what you are doing somewhere else?`

Comment: It brought a (good natured) smile to my face to see the reason for the edit of this question, @Kevin

Comment: @JNK'sMetAccount I won't argue, but this seems logical to me. Many people share their success stories. When an invention is made, it is shared over time with the rest of the scientific community. The same rules apply to things like StackOverflow community, which once was a startup too, and I am sure, also acquired some advise form books and people, who were willing to share.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are already several language-specific proposals on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), for instance (just the first one I saw) [Stack Overflow (in Turkish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish).

Search Area 51 for a proposal in your language of choice and follow/commit to it, then advertise it as you suggest so that it happens sooner.  If you don't find the right language, create a proposal for it.

As to your question of how SO got started, as I understand, Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky had a blog with a bunch of followers, then they started SO and [brought many of their followers with](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html).

Comment: The blog post: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html

Comment: @ShawnChin great, added a link to it.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, codinghorror is Jeff's blog. Joel's at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/. Relevant post: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html

Comment: @ShawnChin Didn't know about that blog post.  But seriously, what's with all the random images?  I guess it's to prevent it from being a wall of text, but wow, haha.

Comment: @casperOne - Those images are slightly more random than normal. Usually, they're [pictures of Taco](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/IMG_0329.jpg) ([source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/)). (BTW - For Science'ing your username change...)

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Taco didn't exist back then, though. Otherwise, he'd be all over that blog post ;p